# Get embedded hyperlinks from cells using INDEX

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I have a cell with `=INDEX(D:D;$E$1)` which spits out various part numbers. 90% of time the result is a hyperlink taking employee to our supplier website.

In google docs search results come in form of part number with hyperlink to that website but not in Excel (I've tried it on 2007, 2010 and 365). In Excel it is just a part number. Is there workaround to get a cell content with hyperlink still attached to it?

If needed I can share that file

Comment: Hi, I had some trouble understanding your question at first so I've edited it to more clearly ask the question you're asking - everything related to how you're using `CELL` to get a row number to feed to your `INDEX` lookup wasn't actually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `INDEX` doesn't return the contents of the target cell including hyperlink, just the cell value. You can use `HYPERLINK` to turn a cell value in the form of a URL back into a clickable link.

So, you're basically doing this:

[image]

And all you get is the text, not a clickable link.

This, though:

[image]

Will do what you want it to do. Since you said it's not *always* a hyperlink, you can protect yourself from bugs by surrounding it with an `IF`, so your final version might look something like:

`=IF(LEFT(INDEX(D:D;$E$1),5)="https",HYPERLINK(INDEX(D:D;$E$1)),INDEX(D:D;$E$1))`